# Logger in src/groovy class

Tags: grails, logging, groovy, src

I am trying to log to a file for my classes under src/groovy. It logs every thing to the console but not to the log file specified. I am not sure why its not working. please help. Here's my code.

config.groovy:

```
log4j = {        
    appenders {
       file name:'file', file:'C:/Users/Desktop/Logs/cms.log'
        }
    info "grails.app"
    debug "grails.app"
    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

My BasicCrawler.groovy class under src/groovy:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class BasicCrawler extends WebCrawler {
private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
//some code
log.debug "name: $name"
}
```

Comment: `file` appender is not used anywhere. Add `root { debug 'file' }` in log4j settings.

Comment: please post it as answer so that i can accept it. it worked for me thanks :)

Comment: Added as requested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` appender is not used anywhere. Add `root { debug 'file' }` in log4j settings to include the appender in root logging.